# PHP date format variable

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I would like to change the date format in the following code:

```
#search for all event start dates
$starts = $sxml->xpath('//event/startdate');

#get the unique start dates of these event
$dates = array_unique($starts);

foreach($dates as $date) {     
   echo "<li class='header'><h1>{$date}</h1></li>" ."\n";
```

currently, it pulls from an XML feed as 25/11/2021 and I would like to show it as Thursday 25 November 2021 - probably as multiple variables. However,  date() is not working.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the DateTime object it can be easy and accurate

```
$dates = ['25/11/2021','24/11/2021','23/11/2021'];

foreach ( $dates as $date){
    $df = (DateTime::CreateFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date))->format('l d F Y');
    echo "<li class='header'><h1>{$df}</h1></li>" ."\n";
}
```

RESULTS

```
<li class='header'><h1>Thursday 25 November 2021</h1></li>
<li class='header'><h1>Wednesday 24 November 2021</h1></li>
<li class='header'><h1>Tuesday 23 November 2021</h1></li>
```

> [PHP Manual for DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)